# Rails model global variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to implement a functionality of messages to display on different pages on my site.
I have created a model for this that contains fields, say `page`, `message`, `active`. If `active=false` the message will not be displayed. This works fine.

Now I want to add a capability to turn all messages on/off for some time. I don't want to update each message and set `active=false` because 1) there can be a lot of messages, 2) I would have to save which messages were active/inactive at the moment of turning off to restore the initial state when turning back on.

This would be very handy if I could use new "class-wide" variable `@@active` in my model. However, using multi-thread app (I use `unicorn`) can cause troubles because `@@active` will not be shared over all processes.

I was not able to google a good solutions for this, maybe someone can help?

Comment: If you created an instance variable in your application controller, does `unicorn` make it visible across all the processes? If so, you might consider that route: use an instance variable in your `application_controller.rb` as a "state variable" for the session.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps create an environment variable called `DISABLE_ALL_MESSAGES` and then override the `message#active` method to refer to `ENV["DISABLE_ALL_MESSAGES"]`:

```
def active
  ENV["DISABLE_ALL_MESSAGES"] && super
end
```

Another option would be to store the setting in the database and refer to it in a similar manner.

Comment: I would think storing it in the database would be the best solution, because it avoids threading issues and makes it easy for an administrator to change this setting at will for all threads.

Comment: If you're hosting on a service like like Heroku or AppFog, it's ridiculously easy to change an environment variable. But you're right that it may be easier to persist it in the database depending on the circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting preload_app=true in your unicorn configuration. This lets unicorn master process to preload the app and all the other workers share the loaded data structure. You might want to move to Ruby Enterprise Edition to share memory across processes.